# Criar programa executavel com php, html e mysql

Tags: php

Olá, gostaria de saber se tem como eu criar uma aplicação em php, usando html e integrar com o mysql, porém depois de criado tem como eu converter para executável, fazendo com que quando ele abra ele execute no localhost do cliente?
Se não, qual a linguagem que vocês me indicariam para fazer um programa que execute em windows e que tenha uma interface amigável para se trabalhar.

Comment: É melhor usar outra linguagem com certeza!

Comment: Qual a linguagem que você me recomenda rray, uma linguagem simples e que possa ter uma interface amigável.

Comment: Delphi ou C#, ambas tem IDEs com vários componentes prontos, você pode arrastar eles para tela e manipular da forma que deseja é mais simples que o HTML, depois você programa as funcionalidades e linka elas aos eventos dos componentes(parecido com os eventos do javascript).

Answer (score 2):

Utilizar o PHP como Software Desktop não é a melhor das opções. Mas você tem duas formas de fazê-lo.

Com o [PHPDESKTOP](https://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/) e com o [PHP-GTK](http://www.php-gtk.com.br/).

Não sou expert em linguagens desktop, mas certamente aconselharão você a utilizar outra linguagem.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, PHP é uma [linguagem interpretada](http://henriquebastos.net/diferencas-entre-linguagem-compilada-e-linguagem-interpretada/) e como tal, não se gera arquivos executáveis dela. Você pode até criar aplicações desktop utilizando o [PHP-GTK](http://www.php-gtk.com.br/), porém como a linguagem não foi criada com esse objetivo, diversos problemas podem ocorrer.

Se seu objetivo é executar o PHP (de forma quase completa) sem a necessidade de instalar nada no cliente (além do próprio PHP), pode utilizar o servidor interno da linguagem. O comando abaixo cria um servidor local e permite o acesso ao PHP em localhost.

```
php -S localhost:80 -t /path/to/php/site
```

basta alterar o numero 80 pela porta que você desejar e alterar o `/path/to/php/site` para o caminho de seu script PHP