# É possível criar uma aplicação desktop usando apenas PHP, HTML, CSS e jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, aplicação-desktop

Apesar de saber que o PHP é uma linguagem para web, gostaria de saber uma coisa. É possível em qualquer situação que seja criar uma aplicação, sistema ou um aplicativo apenas com PHP+HTML+CSS+jQuery que sirva para um ambiente fora da web (num Windows ou Mac, por exemplo)?

Já ouvi falar em PHP para Android, mas para desktop ouvi falar de um tal de GTK que muito mal entendi o que era.

Comment: Relacionada SOEn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable

Comment: [Criar programa executavel com php, html e mysql](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103242/91)

Comment: Possivel é. Recomendável, talvez não.

Comment: fora da web você quer dizer localhost, rede interna? Nesse caso sim é possível

Answer (score 15, accepted):

É possível usar PHP para fazer aplicações desktop reais, eu [já fiz porque fui obrigado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133354/101), mas ficou horrível e logo foi descartado. PHP decidiu que seria uma linguagem de nicho, e isto é bom. Ou pelo menos era quando ela seguia a filosofia adequada para este nicho. Hoje só vejo uma razão para tentar fazer isso: não querer aprender outra linguagem.

Tem algumas tentativas de fazer o *browser* como plataforma desktop, mas os resultados ainda estão bem aquém do que se pode esperar. Ou seja, faria uma aplicação web que rodaria em um navegador modificado para parecer que é desktop. Aí o PHP funcionaria como servidor do mesmo jeito, só que não parece nada com uma aplicação desktop, terá muitas limitações. E terá que repensar o jeito de programar de tal forma que é melhor aprender outra coisa e fazer direito.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "fazer direto" +1

Comment: Não concordo pq o conceito de desktop é muito além de criar exe. PHP é linguagem de script feito para Web. O Desenvolvimento é Web e vc usa o GTK para fazer isso.
Enfim.

Comment: @fabricio_wm ?!?!?!?

Comment: @fabricio_wm vc leu a pergunta? E PHP também roda direto no console, sem servidor HTTP nenhum. A parte "web" é feita normalmente pelo apache, nginx etc, e não pelo PHP. Concordo que o **hipertexto** seja uma especialidade do PHP. Web é consequência apenas.

Comment: A pergunta principal não é essa, @Bacco.

Comment: Bom, o título foi "É possível criar uma aplicação desktop usando apenas PHP, HTML, CSS e jQuery?", e acho que a resposta foi adequada. Só fiz uma observação adicional, pois vc comentou que "o desenvolvimento é web", e isso não me faz o mínimo sentido só pelo fato de ser PHP. De qq forma, não vou me estender muito aqui, pq nem a pergunta e nem a resposta são minhas, e o autor aceitou esta resposta.

Comment: Inclusive ele usa o termo apenas php, html, css e jquery.
Eu respondi exatamente o que ele perguntou.
Desktop tem acesso a serviços da máquina. 
É possível fazer essa aplicação desktop não simplesmente pq tem um EXE e sim pq eu tenho as características de uma aplicação desktop?

Comment: @fabricio_wm atualmente, com local storage, praticamente você tem tudo pra rodar standalone e local, até mesmo sem o PHP. Por outro lado, o PHP rodando local e sem servidor web tem acesso a muito mais coisa do OS, e com exec() você faz praticamente tudo o que não puder chamar nativamente. Juntando com o GTK, sai do browser e tem UI própria, com janelas, formulários e controles, então realmente vira uma aplicação desktop. Pode inclusive fazer comunicação serial com um ECF. Agora, que tem linguagem melhor pra isso, tem. Mas não dá pra dizer que não é um app desktop.;

Comment: @fabricio_wm mas como eu já comentei na própria pergunta, eu acho uma solução porca, que fique claro isso. E de certa forma foi o que o bigown respondeu.

Comment: Agora fico me perguntando o que será que tem de errado na resposta pra merecer negativo?

Comment: A pergunta tende a ser boa, mas falta entendimento de quem negativou do que significa **aplicação desktop**. Os comentários despedaçam a pergunta(alguns comentários.) Talvez @bigown a resposta esteja **simples** para aqueles que estão acostumados a lerem seus **livros-respostas**.

Comment: Bom, acredito que a resposta dada foi boa e objetiva. Por isso aceitei a resposta

Comment: @durtto pode ser, mas seria um absurdo negativar por isso. Tem gente que já me negativou porque a resposta era grande :D Mas é o que eu digo, a pessoa não justifica porque sabe que não tem nada errado, eu odeio deixar algo errado, se tivesse de fato, eu queria saber o que é.

Answer (score 11):

A pergunta é sobre executar o PHP como um software desktop mas ao mesmo tempo comenta sobre se é possível executar o PHP "fora da web".

Subentendo que "fora da web" seja também poder executar o PHP dentro de uma LAN (rede local sem internet, a grosso modo) e não necessariamente como um binário ".exe".

Nesse caso sim, é possível criar um sistema em PHP para ser executado sem necessidade de usar internet, sem necessidade de contratar um provedor de hospedagem e tampouco sem precisar comprar um domínio (www... .com). Basta instalar num PC na rede local e liberar as portas para acesso via browser. Outros PCs na mesma rede poderão acessar pelo browser como se estivesse acessando um website, porém, é privado. Somente a rede local terá acesso.

**Local Area Network (LAN)**

Normalmente pensamos no PHP como um construtor de websites e linguagem voltada a internet, mas obviamente pode-se também construir softwares como controle contábil, controle de clientes, estoque, cartão de ponto integrado com leitor de cartão. Também pode usar para criar um aplicativo de caixa para um supermercado, por exemplo, integrado com leitor de código de barras, QR Code e tudo mais. O PHP é independente de internet pois um "ambiente WEB" não precisa estar necessariamente aberto a internet.

O que complica mais são as funções visuais pois a interface é em HTML, CSS e JavaScript rodando sob um browser. Nesse caso são limitações do browser e não do PHP em si. Exemplo, poder acessar o Windows Explorer e clicar e arrastar arquivos para dentro de um explorer em HTML. Coisas desse tipo são complexas para se fazer por um web browser e eram impossíveis ou super complicadas no passado (até 13 anos atrás), mas hoje em dia é mais fácil encontrar soluções especialmente porque numa rede local podemos ter controle e impor regras aos PCs client-side. Além do mais é uma situação muito específica de interação com sistema de arquivos onde nem todos os aplicativos, dentre os mais comuns, necessitam.

Todas as outras funções como acessar uma impressora, executar comandos e inclusive fazer um reboot ou shutdown no Sistema Operacional, são possíveis e acessíveis.

**PHP Built-in web server**

No PHP 5.4 foi introduzido um servidor embutido no compilador do PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

O uso é muito simples, dispensando um servidor web terceiro como LightHTTP, Nginx, Apache, IIS, entre outros. **Não quer dizer que os substitua.*

Isso significa que poderá apenas invocar o PHP por uma linha de comando, a qual iniciará um servidor web embutido.

Novamente, se pensarmos no PHP somente como algo voltado a WEB, ficaremos muito limitados achando que o PHP não é adequado para outros ambientes. No entanto, é possível, por exemplo, executar scripts PHP dentro de um [Raspberry PI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/), por exemplo.

Com o Raspberry podemos construir desde um simples switch de leds a um robô com inteligência artificial. E por quê não poder controlar isso com PHP ou ao menos algumas funções que poderiam ser escritas de forma mais prática e rápida com PHP?

Isso é possível e já muito utilizado hoje em dia. Simples de fazer, simples de manter. Só precisa de um editor de textos e um console (aquela telinha preta) ou um browser para testar.

Há mil e uma utilidades, por exemplo, construir em PHP um roteador de rede, um sistema de alarme, roteador de chamadas telefônicas, controlador VOIP, um carrinho de controle remoto, enviar comandos diretamente para rede de telefonia (isso mesmo, diretamente para uma linha de telefone, sem precisar do telefone), entre muitas coisas.

Um programador PHP não precisa ser necessariamente um "fazedor de sites". Há "zilhões" de aplicações que se pode fazer além de websites.

**O PHP compilado como um binário .exe**

É possível, conforme já comentado nas outras respostas. É um conceito antigo e acredito que podemos dizer, "defasado". Atualmente temos melhores recursos, conforme mencionado acima, e não precisamos necessariamente pensar que um aplicativo desktop deve ser um "binário .exe" ou ter aquela clássica aparência de software desktop.

É comum vermos aplicações PHP que rodam com um webserver e um browser, porém "disfarçados" dentro de uma janela compilada em outra linguagem desktop, para que tenha uma aparência de software desktop. Esse tipo de uso é horrível e desnecessário. Mas vai da escolha de cada um. Pessoalmente não vejo problema no usuário abrir um aplicativo usando um browser e que tenha ali todos os recursos de um browser inclusive ver o fonte HTML, a barra de URL, etc. Muitos alegam questões se segurança, mas nesse ponto entramos num outro assunto muito extenso, o qual não convém comentar aqui.

Todavia, compilar scripts PHP como um binário não é algo recomendável devido as limitações e dificuldades que encontrará. Mas é possível sim. Se você for mazoquista, vá por esse caminho.

**Cross-platform**

O PHP é cross-platform. Ou seja, pode ser executado em ambiente Linux (incluindo OS-X/Mac) ou Windows. Obviamente há funções e recursos específicos para cada ambiente, no entanto, de um modo geral, o mesmo código PHP que escreveu sob ambiente Windows funcionará em outros ambientes. Isso é uma grande vantagem. Fácil de construir e fácil de manter.

**Observações**

Há certos casos onde é melhor usar numa linguagem específica. A escolha depende  dos requisitos do aplicativo. Apenas não pense de forma exagerada como se pudesse construir um colisor de hádrons com PHP, por exemplo. Ou como se o PHP fosse algo limitado e focado somente para fazer websites com $_GET, $_POST, explode(), strpos()...

Answer (score 6):

Existia um projeto chamado php-gtk, mas que foi decontinuado.

GTK é uma biblioteca ou api gráfica que fornece os objetos gráficos muito utilizado em ambiente linux, mas que também possui versões para windows e mac. Era inserido as linhas para criar as janelas, botões, etc, que era usado em um script php.

Além desse tem o WxPHP que é mais recente (mas que eu nunca usei), WinBinder que é só pra windows e php-qt.

O que existe (e é mais utilizado) são script php para rodar num console (linha de comando)

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que pude entender pesquisando, sim, é possível utilizando uma extensão do PHP chamada GTK, e sim, é crossplatform (Windows, Linux, Mac, [insira aqui o SO]). Pelo que pude ler, não é PHP puro que é utilizado, e sim uma versão mista, PHP + GTK, que provavelmente te da suporte a coisas mais internas no sistema.

Pelo que pude notar o site em si não te dá muita definição do que a coisa faz em si, e como mas...

segue link:
[http://gtk.php.net/](http://gtk.php.net/null.php?language=pt-BR)