# Qual é o conceito do GTK? É recomendável usá-lo?

Tags: php, gtk, aplicação-desktop

O GTK é para 'criar' aplicações para desktop usando o PHP, quero saber como ele funciona, é um navegador modificado, com um servidor próprio?

Tenho interesse em fazer algo parecido, algo para transformar o desenvolvimento em PHP, tanto para web quanto para desktop e mobile. E para isso preciso entender o conceito dessas aplicações que fazem isso.

Quais suas vantagens e desvantagens? Ainda que muitos não achem bom criar algo assim, vejo a possibilidade de se tornar algo realmente de qualidade, pois o PHP é uma linguagem de qualidade, e pode ser feito um trabalho para torná-la uma linguagem desktop também.

Comment: "o PHP é uma linguagem de qualidade, e pode ser feito um trabalho para torna-la uma linguagem desktop também." - na verdade não é uma linguagem de qualidade, e pra desktop tem bastante coisa melhor. PHP presta bem pra scripts rápidos, como o pessoal usava normalmente pra web. Pra trazer pra desktop, só vai estar andando pra trás. É como abrir e fechar gabinete de PC usando faca de ponta. Talvez você fique muito bom nisso, mas usar a chave certa vai ser mais vantajoso. Por exemplo, eu já vi obras de arte feitas com o MS Paint, mas é coisa feita por lazer. Dificilmente viraria profissão.

Comment: Sei que há linguagens muito melhor para desktop que são focadas nessa plataforma. Pra mim não existe uma linguagem ruim, e php é uma linguagem de qualidade, se não não seria usada na grande maioria dos dites wev. QUero que intendam que não é tornar o PHP melhor que um Java ou C# da vida, mas sim algo útil no desenvolvimento desktop também.

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, mas é que normalmente os defeitos do PHP foram aceitos na web por na época ter sido inovação, e melhor que o Asp da época, que era praticamente a única outra opção. Mas achei importante mencionar, pois hoje o PHP está tentando imitar coisas que já existiam em linguagens de pelo menos 30 anos atrás, e sem a mesma qualidade, e no conceito errado. Como eu disse, pode ser que você faça coisas maravilhosas com isso. Mas é importante entender que sempre vai estar pra trás. E não é só a linguagem que conta, mas a plataforma/runtime que tem por trás dela.

Comment: Notar que eu estou falando sem nenhum preconceito, eu uso PHP normalmente. Foi apenas uma opinião baseada no que eu conheço da implementação técnica, e não em gosto. E isso não é uma crítica à sua pergunta, que pode até dar respostas interessantes. Foi apenas um contraponto ao trecho que eu destaquei.

Comment: Sim sim eu entendo, porém discordo em dizer que não é uma linguagem de qualidade, depende em que mãos ela está, naqueles que a sabem usar corretamente resulta em um trabalho de qualidade, nas outras nem tanto. Vejo apenas como um leque a mais que se pode abrir, não para se tornar algo profissional, mas para virar um quebra galho, em aplicações desktops sem ter tão questionado como o gtk.

Comment: Só tou dizendo que o PHP é extremamente mal feito. As funções do PHP são completamente mal elaboradas, e sequer tem um padrão na nomenclatura e na ordem dos parâmetros. Não tou falando que um código escrito em PHP não possa ser bem escrito (dentro do que a linguagem permite) Isso só depende das mãos de quem usa. Tem códigos muito bem feitos em PHP, e isso é mérito do programador que está usando, e não da linguagem. O artigo não é muito bom, mas antes de sair alguma resposta, aqui já tem um resumo: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP-GTK

Comment: De curiosidade, aqui tem um artigo que dá uma visão geral do PHP: http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Desculpa me intrometer após vários meses no assunto, mas falar que o PHP é mal feito, mostra o quanto você foi mal respondido.

Comparar linguagens como java e C# que nasceram depois de muito tempo, ja com foco no que faz não vale. Ou comparar PHP com C, nada se compara à C.

Me denomido programador, por isso uso mono (C# para windows), Python GTK para linux e php para web, mas tenho muitos projetos em muitas outras linguagens como java, então não estou só defendendo o PHP ok?

Quando ouvir falar que a linguagem é mal feita, leve em consideração que o php 4 para o 5 eles levaram um tombo muito grande, e por isso todas as versões começaram a sair com compatibilidade. 10% dos programadores sabem a diferença entre PHP 5.3 e 5.3.3 por exemplo, usam a função date() achando que a linguagem não presta, por exemplo.

O outro ali comparou com crack, que só usam PHP por que outros usam, mesmo sendo uma linguagem que tem mais de 1 commit a cada 2 horas. Se você for pensar assim, só se pode desenvolver pra web de windows, por que pra mim tirando o PHP a unica coisa que presta é C#, dai programadores linux estão fora dessa, por que monodevelop nem se compara ao visual studio.

Então uma dica que posso te dar, é não ouvir quem diz que uma coisa é melhor que outra, ou gosta mais disso do que aquilo, nunca ouça gente assim.

Se for levar esses pontos em consideração, toda linguagem tem seus problemas, como por exemplo compartilhamento de tipos do javascript, ou usar comentários como parte da programação, em java.

Posso te garantir que PHP é uma linguagem e tanto, tem melhorado cada vez mais, e a partir do PHP 6 a linguagem vem se modelando para atingir linguagens grandes com apoio de muitas empresas grandes.

Sobre a pergunta em particular, tento manter o PHP-GTK na comunidade à bastante tempo, tenho muitos projetos escritos para tal, inclusive iniciei o movimento para dar inicio ao [php-gtk3](https://github.com/scorninpc/php-gtk3-tests). Como você disse, PHP é uma linguagem forte, com uma curva de aprendizado muito grande, porem ela é uma linguagem script, então todo o resto é feito por curioso, se posso dizer isso.

Por experiência própria PHP-GTK é um hobby, uma curiosidade que mato para saber até onde posso ir, já que para desenvolver uma extensão por exemplo, trabalho com no mínimo 3 linguagens, mas segue alguns dos meus pontos de vista

1 - Não faria nada profissional como PHP-GTK
2 - É muito estável e existe muita documentação sobre PHP e sobre GTK
3 - É rápido de fazer fronts que ajudam no dia a dia

Vantagens
- Como já citado, é rápido desenvolvimento, rápido aprendizado
- É estável, não fica dando crash do nada
- É realmente multiplataforma
- Comunidade muito receptiva

Desvantagens
- Desatualizado
- Os temas para windows são horríveis
- É lento, pois é um bind de uma lib rodando em um script (apesar de não dar diferença alguma nas maquinas atuais)
- e MUITA gente sem propriedade nenhuma fala muito mal

Novamente, desculpa a resposta tardia, mas é que cai na pergunta após uma busca que fiz, e achei que podia acrescentar algo visto que nada acrescentou muito à sua pergunta propriamente dita

Comment: Onde na pergunta é falado que php é mal feito ou se compara com. C# e Java? Li 2x e não achei nada disso.

Comment: Acho que ele se refere aos comentários... @diegofm. Mas é normal, no Brasil o pessoal ainda está nesse nível de sempre querer falar mal do PHP. Aí vira modinha falar mal para parecer cool ou expert.  Bem colocado pois GTK para PHP, há 12 anos atrás era bem precário e muitos dos que falam mal viveram essa época, inclusive eu e concordo se falarmos dessa época. Mas o tempo passou e a ferramente melhorou.. Hoje é algo bem estável e aceitável. Mas como alguns ainda vivem de referências defasadas, continuam disseminando erroneamente.

Comment: @diegofm, realmente foi falado que php é uma linguagem mal feita nos 2 comentários que haviam. Por isso me achei na obrigação de responder a pergunta, mas não consegui não falar do por que o php não é uma linguagem mal feita. Se foi você quem negativou, por favor revise. Obrigado

Comment: @BrunoPitteliGonçalves não negativei, se eu fosse negativar, teria que fazer com as 2 resposta, ambas tem manifestações pessoais influenciando o conteudo da resposta. Preferi não entrar neste mérito.

Comment: Finalmente alguma resposta que realmente foi uma resposta, porque aqui na comunidade acaba que tendo um grupo mais favorecido por ter pontuação alta, deixando o que eles falam como certo mesmo todos sabendo que não é o certo. Basta ver a outra resposta com avaliações positivas e essa daqui que realmente está sendo útil para a pergunta sendo negativada, provavelmente por discordar desse tal grupo, muitas vezes já me ocorreu isso, por não ter tanta experiência acabam pensando que podem doutrinar.

Comment: Agora sobre a resposta, vai me ajudar a retomar as buscas, pois tinha parado, por causa dessas manifestações péssimas sobre o Gtk etc, não sobre o PHP, porque sei que ele é odiado por muitos, mas na minha concepção é uma linguagem única, permite que você faça muito mais que as outras com muito menos trabalho.. Vou tentar retomar as pesquisas sobre o assunto.

Comment: Legal que tenha gostado @lvcs. Se puder ajudar, o grupo do site php-gtk.com.br e bruno.pitteli.com.br, estou sempre por la pra dar uma mão!

Comment: Eu falo o que é o certo pela minha experiência. Eu sei que essa resposta não é boa. Ela não fala coisa com coisa, mistura coisas, joga um monte de opinião sem base. Tem alguma informação útil, mas apenas diz o que o AP queria ouvir. Foi dado referências que PHP tem problemas. Essa resposta não deu nenhuma que PHP é bem feita. A resposta reclama de manifestações pessoais, mas essa resposta só faz isso. Cada um pode achar o que quiser, cada um pode aceitar o que quiser, cada um pode ignorar o senso comum e teimar em algo. Farei o que já deveria ter feito desde o princípio.Só daria opinião mesmo

Comment: @BrunoPitteliGonçalves como você mesmo disse, "me achei na obrigação de responder a pergunta, mas não consegui não falar do por que o php não é uma linguagem mal feita.", acho legal da sua parte deixar claro isso (e é realmente algo que eu tinha notado ao ler). Se quiser saber alguns dos pontos técnicos pelos quais tenho tranquilidade absoluta em dizer que é mal-feita, este artigo pode ajudar: https://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/ - mesmo que tenha ficado desatualizado o artigo, tenho certeza que bem mais da metade dos problemas mencionados ainda é verdade.

Comment: Além disso, só para você se situar quanto a mim: Eu uso PHP desde as primeiras versões, quando saí do Asp clássico por volta de 2001, e adotei como linguagem-base para aplicações Web desde então. Inclusive, estudei os internals um bocado, pois considerei estender o PHP em C da mesma forma que faço com outras linguagens, mas percebi que para coisas mais complexas, não compensava. Não tenho a mínima pretensão de que isso mude sua opinião, só quis mencionar para você entender que não se trata de um mero curioso opinando, e sim alguém que teve a preocupação de conhecer a ferramenta que usa.

Comment: Isto posto, toda colocação contrária é bem-vinda, mas fica a sugestão de contextualizar então, para que seja mais produtiva a contraposição de idéias. Só não se esqueça que da minha parte, não se trata de um fã de outra linguagem criticando. Eu uso PHP onde o PHP funciona para o que eu preciso, e outras linguagens onde o PHP não atende bem. E entendo que esse é o normal de qualquer programador que preze por usar a ferramenta mais adequada para cada caso.

Comment: @Bacco o curioso é que há um parágrafo dizendo que **não dá para usar PHP-GTK em nada profissional**. Essa parte o AP ignorou. A resposta também diz  claramente que o PHP é uma linguagem de *script*. O que o AP e alguns usuário teimam em dizer que não é. É difícil precisar de GUI em *scripts*. Em um ERP, eu entendo que GUI é importante. Mas uma linguagem de *script* não é adequada para isso. Dá para fazer, claro, mas é a ferramenta errada. O autor da resposta parece entender bem isso. Concordo com vários pontos da resposta, o maior problema dela são as opiniões sem base alguma, o resto é bom.

Comment: @bigown de fato eu acho que a resposta tem vários pontos bem legais. Nem teria comentado nada se não fossem os desdobramentos nos comments, inclusive, mas como foi colocada pelo autor da pergunta uma situação de "pontuação alta e de grupos favorecidos" e um papo de "doutrinar", e na resposta tem uma indicação sobre ser mal respondido quando alguém diz que PHP é mal feita, achei por bem deixar claros alguns pontos. Realmente ficou muita coisa opinativa no meio, o que está atrapalhando um pouco a resposta. Talvez a parte opinativa tivesse ficado melhor apenas como comentário mesmo.

Comment: A resposta pecou em algumas coisas, como tentar refutar o que eu disse e não dizer coisa com coisa, falar que toda linguagem tem problemas, e ficar algo sem sentido e que não pegar em nada problemático mesmo, a resposta fala para não ouvir quem diz que uma coisa é melhor que outra, exatamente o que a resposta está fazendo fortemente em vários pontos, em uma análise cuidadosa ela é bem opinativa (não há base pra quase nada) e fala de muita coisa que não foi perguntado, fala de coisas que não foram faladas em outros *posts*, fala de PHP 6, não cabe tudo em comentário. Mas é justa com o PHP-GTK.

Comment: @bigown e Bacco, novamente vocês veem somente falando da linguagem. Em nenhum momento, quem perguntou, perguntou o que vocês achavam da linguagem PHP. Sobre o que você ACHAM, estão se apegando em uma linguagem de 5 anos atrás (o artigo que você mandou é de 2012). Nessa época quase nenhum programador PHP sabia o que era um framework. Quer comparar PHP com C#? Tente comparar PHP+Zend com C#, no mínimo, pois ele só ficou conhecido depois de ter o .NET por trás . Então assim, sei que todos tem suas experiências, e se formos para falar de experiências, também tenho as minhas

Comment: @BrunoPitteliGonçalves agora você resolveu especular sobre coisas que não tem a mínima chance de você saber se é verdade, o que não é. Pelo menos ficou claro que seus critérios são subjetivos e especulativos demais. Assim como tinha especulado sobre coisas técnicas, agora especula sobre o que fazemos. Essencialmente não mudou nada no artigo. A linguagem não foi completamente mudada, o que seria um completo *non-sense*. Só de imaginar que isso poderia ter ocorrido já indica a falta de critério. Não vale mais a pena falar mais nada depois dessa.Obrigado por confirmar o que falei sobre o PHP-GTK.

Answer (score 11):

<sup>Isto deveria ser mais um comentário, mas ficaria muito longo. E no fundo responde a pergunta, que provavelmente é opinativa (sei lá se deveria estar aberta). Mas pelo menos respondi sobre o uso do GTK no PHP, que é o que pede a pergunta, e tentei ser justo e embasar a resposta como dá, mas admito que tem um pouco de opinião</sup>

## GTK

[GTK](https://www.gtk.org/) é um conjunto de controles de acesso nativo ao gerenciador de janelas de alguns sistemas operacionais. Ele foi feito originalmente para o Linux e portado para outros SOs com maior ou menor grau de sucesso. Ele não é um navegador.

Para dizer sobre vantagens e desvantagens teria que comparar com alguma outra coisa. Entendo que o pedido é sobre o PHP-GTK e não ao GTK puro com outros kits.

GTK (puro) não é dos melhores kits de controles e gerenciadores de janelas. Ele não funciona bem no Windows, especialmente na versão suportada pelo PHP-GTK. Mas dá pra usar bem, pelo menos em Linux.

## PHP-GTK

O PHP-GTK comparando com [PHP-Qt](https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-qt/), [wxPHP](https://wxphp.org/) ou outros kits eu não sei, não conheço usuários destes kits. Certamente eles sofrem dos mesmos problemas do PHP-GTK, inclusive a falta de uma comunidade suportando-os. Um parece abandonado e o outro quase.

## Comparando com tecnologia de outra linguagem

Se a comparação for com o uso do desktop em outras linguagens, a comparação ficaria até injusta. A única vantagem que vejo nele é a pessoa que já conhece bem o PHP continuar nele. Mas isso por si só pode ser visto como desvantagem também, inclusive para essa pessoa. Usar a ferramenta errada neste caso pode ser bem mais trágico do que ela aprender outra linguagem. Claro que se ela não tem capacidade de aprender outra linguagem, aí tanto faz, qualquer coisa será ruim. A lista de desvantagens é enorme e vou citando algumas delas ao longo do texto, os problemas mais específicos eu não lembro, faz tempo que fiz isto.

## Web X desktop

Os modelos de programação web e desktop são completamente diferentes. A adaptação não é fácil. Aprender uma nova linguagem é mais fácil que aprender um outro jeito de programar. E se a pessoa tentar programar desktop como se fosse web será trágico. A melhor parte será a que não funcionar. Curiosamente o PHP até tem algumas coisas úteis para desktop que ninguém usa para web. Aí ele terá que usar coisas que nunca ouviu falar. O PHP-GTK não foi desenvolvido usando os recursos mais modernos do PHP, que, ironicamente, ajudariam mais uma aplicação desktop. É show de horrores de coisas erradas com isto.

O ambiente de execução do PHP foi feito para executar *scripts* e não tem nenhuma facilidade que ajude executar uma aplicação *desktop*. Pelo contrário, ele cria dificuldades para este tipo de aplicação, mesmo no `php-win`, cujo nome engana bem.

## Minha experiência

Eu tenho experiência com isso pra fazer um quebra-galho. Foi **a pior decisão** que tomei na computação.

Eu usei a mesma [versão do PHP-GTK que está disponível hoje](http://gtk.php.net/download.php?language=en-US). O fato de não haver evolução depois de tanto tempo já mostra como é uma tecnologia que ninguém quer investir.

## PHP não ajuda

PHP não é uma linguagem de qualidade e existem diversas fontes mostrando isso. Ela é usável e dá para fazer bastante coisa interessante com ela. Não é que ela seja trágica, não recomendável, nada disso. Mas não dá pra comparar com outras linguagens *mainstream*.

É opinião, claro, não nego isto, mas ela é baseada em experiência extensiva de uso real (e sou um apaixonado por linguagens em geral, dedico boa parte do meu tempo livre estudando o funcionamento de linguagens, não sou um leigo no assunto dando uma opinião qualquer, ainda que eu não seja um "doutor" no assunto) e muitos relatos bastantes detalhados sobre isso, entre eles, o *linkado* em comentário do Bacco.

## Inconsistências na pergunta

Até onde sei, PHP não é a linguagem usada para desenvolvimento da maioria da web. Se isso for verdade é preciso apresentar os dados. Eu já vi alguns que mostram o contrário, mas como não são dos mais confiáveis nem vou postar. Principalmente não é a escolha quando a decisão foi feita de forma profissional. Até os sites mais conhecidos que começaram com PHP foi assim porque o fundador não sabia usar outra coisa. E hoje eles vão migrando para outras coisas.

O problema de quem avalia qualquer coisa é que sempre que a pessoa não tem informação suficiente para fazer isto, [ela não tem condições de avaliar sua própria condição de avaliar e entra em um círculo vicioso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Este fenômeno é conhecido como [martelo dourado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument). [As pessoas não lidam bem com informação que a desagrada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A9s_de_confirma%C3%A7%C3%A3o) e ela não costuma perceber isto. PHP não é uma [panaceia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panaceia).

## Popularidade

O critério de que algo que é muito usado tem qualidade leva à conclusão que crack (é, falo da pedra) tem qualidade, afinal tem muito mais usuários que o PHP.

A maioria dos usuários de PHP optaram por esta linguagem porque outros optaram por ela (em época que não tinha nada melhor **para web**). É um fenômeno de manada e não de decisão consciente com critérios científicos bem definidos. E é muito comum que a escolha tenha sido feita porque é o que a pessoa conseguiu aprender (aprender PHP é muito fácil, usar nem tanto, mas a primeira barreira sempre é o que a pessoa se apega, não olha para o que vem a seguir, o que é mais um motivo para a decisão ser errada). Inclusive absurdamente tem cursos superiores que usam esta linguagem como instrumento básico de programação, o que me faz questionar a qualidade do curso. Obviamente que o aluno deste curso também será aquele que só saberá fazer o que foi ensinado neste curso ruim e não criará vida própria, que deveria ser o principal objetivo de um curso superior.

Mas se for para usar isto como critério de definição, então não use o PHP-GTK, essencialmente ninguém o usa e é um projeto praticamente abandonado e bem mal ajambrado. Não há o menor apoio da comunidade.

Todas as aplicações que eu vi, até mesmo apresentadas pelos criadores deste módulo, sempre foram muito mal feitas. Sim, se o programador for bom dá pra fazer algo bem feito em PHP, mas por alguma razão ninguém conseguiu demonstrar isso com PHP-GTK. Sempre a pessoa que pega isso acha que vai fazer melhor que os outros. Talvez isto se explique com "as pessoas que optaram por fazer algo em desktop com PHP sejam os piores programadores desta linguagem", sei lá. Mesmo que não seja, grande parte dos consumidores de crack são pessoas inteligentes que acharam que aquilo ia fazer bem pra elas.

Mesmo os mais fanáticos usuários de PHP rechaçam seu uso para desktop deixando isto relegado pra uns poucos gatos pingados que acham que sabem mais do que os outros mais experientes que eles.

## Mobile

PHP para mobile chega ser quase uma brincadeira.

## Apoio ao que digo

A resposta aceita diz basicamente a mesma coisa que eu disse aqui. No começo a resposta fala de alguns pontos sobre os comentários e o que eu escrevi. Essa parte é bem confusa, mistura coisas, faz comparações incabíveis, não possui base alguma, tem contradições e até foge do senso comum, mostrado até que falta entendimento de alguns assuntos falados.

A parte que fala do PHP-GTK é boa e coloca alguns pontos que eu não havia colocado. Destaco:

> (PHP ela é uma linguagem script, então todo o resto é feito por curioso

Isto é uma grande verdade. Pena que muita gente ache que não é isso. E softwares com GUI geralmente não são *scripts*.

> iniciei o movimento para dar inicio ao php-gtk3

Isso mesmo, pararam no PHP-GTK 2, que diga-se de passagem não é tão estável assim e a própria comunidade admite isso.

> Por experiência própria PHP-GTK é um hobby. Não faria nada profissional como PHP-GTK.

Não questiono o uso por *hobby*, eu respondi para uso profissional. Não dá, ninguém usa. O autor daquela resposta que parece gostar não usa e não mostra alguém que use **com sucesso em aplicações profissionais de qualidade**.

> É muito estável e existe muita documentação sobre PHP e sobre GTK

Minha experiência foi diferente. Veja o [site do PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) e decida por você se é uma tecnologia que tem comunidade, atenção, etc.

> É rápido de fazer fronts que ajudam no dia a dia... é rápido desenvolvimento, rápido aprendizado

Isso é característica do GTK e de forma geral todos as GUIs.

> É estável, não fica dando crash do nada

Não é minha experiência, pelo contrário.

> É realmente multiplataforma

Há controvérsias, mesmo entre os mais ferrenhos defensores do GTK.

> Comunidade muito receptiva

Não tenho dúvida, não tem quase ninguém para causar problema.

> Desatualizado

Sim, muito.

> Os temas para windows são horríveis

Dificulta o uso, não é intuitivo para esse usuário, há limitação e até tem coisas que não funcionam corretamente. O mesmo ocorre no MacOS. E em pequeno grau se o Linux usar KDE ou outro gerenciador de desktop.

> É lento, pois é um bind de uma lib rodando em um script

Exato.

> MUITA gente sem propriedade nenhuma fala muito mal

Muitas com propriedade total falam muito mal. Inclusive todas que tentaram e desistiram da tecnologia. Não tem muita gente falando bem. O próprio autor que tentou falar bem só conseguiu falar que ela não é uma tecnologia adequada.

Em outubro de 2018 em conversei com o Rasmus Lerdorf no Intercon e ele disse que PHP é uma linguagem para *backend web*, nada mais, não há a menor intenção em suportar outros cenários.

[image: Antonio Maniero e Rasmus Lerdorf no Intercon 2018]

## Conclusão

Claramente seu uso não é recomendável com PHP. Com C e outras linguagens (C++, JS, Perl, Python, Lua, talvez Java, entre as mais conhecidas), no Linux dá para usar bem. Mas cada um pode fazer o que bem entende.

Se quiser usar o GTK, até use, mas com outra linguagem. PHP é boa para web.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: É claro que nao se sobre sai sobre linguagens consolidadas, mas tem poo, logo não se torna muito diferente para desenvolvimento desktop, porem a maioria dos usuarios estão acostumados com o php estruturao. Um site de estatísticas: https://w3techs.com/technologies/history_overview/programming_language/ms/y

Comment: Algum link com as tais falhas? Entendi sobre o gtk, vou me aprofundar nas buscas.

Comment: Essa estatística é um completo absurdo. Por isso nem tem metodologia. Os problemas são descritos individualmente, não tem nada que que consolide em um lugar só.

Answer (score 2):

O GTK é um toolkit para criar interfaces gráficas com "bindings" para várias linguagens, não só o PHP. Ele não é um navegador modificado nem um servidor mas sim uma biblioteca de componentes gráficos que interagem diretamente com a interface gráfica do micro.

Nunca usei com PHP (as aplicações GUI que mantenho são feitas com GTK em C) então não posso opinar muito sobre mas, de cara, posso te adiantar que o código gerado para GTK não serve para uma interface web posto que são conceitos radicalmente diferentes.