# Há algum problema em usar Java para aplicação de automação comercial no dektop? Ou é melhor fazer para web usando PHP?

Tags: php, java, aplicação-desktop

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto para desktop usando JavaFx e PostgreSQL, porém comecei a ler sobre Java e achei muitos contras sobre essa linguagem de programação (lentidão, por exemplo), então estou pensando em desenvolver para web utilizando o PHP + MySQL.

O sistema é para o controle geral de um mini mercado, que posteriormente pode ser usado para gerenciar duas unidades do mesmo em locais separados, onde será integrado com TEF e PDV.

Comment: Acho que ninguém é a favor do java! ok exceto as pessoas jurídicas.

Comment: Olá, sua pergunta é baseada em opiniões, logo não é aceita no site. No php não é possível desenvolver aplicações desktop (exceto pelo gtk), todas linguagens tem seus pos e contras, e não há so o Java, para desktop tente o C#, ou faça wb com PHP.

Comment: Mais qual seria melhor para essa situação? uma aplicação desktop ou uma aplicação desktop ?

Comment: Depende mais do cliente, da pra fazer das duas formas, mas vejo o web como uma melhor opção, pois em muitos lugares as máquinas da empresa são fracas, se o sistema desktop não se sair bem no pc da empresa a empresa vai colocar a culpa no sistema e não no pc ruim. Um sistema web não tria esse problema, porém muitos ficam em duvida quanto a segurança de uma aplicação web.

Comment: java fx serve tanto para desktop quanto para web. E eu ainda acredito no preceito de que quem faz a linguagem ruim é o programador ruim. Se você não fizer "mau uso" dos recursos das linguagem, dificilmente ela vai lhe causar problemas.

Comment: Eu tbm penso assim, porém ouvi dizer que o java se torna lento e seria necessario um computador de certa forma "melhor" para rodar os programas sem travar, isso é verdade? o java é realmente lento?

Comment: Com relação a java você sabe me dizer se é fácil integrar as impressoras fiscais e os teclados específicos ?

Comment: Qualquer programa desktop que faça mau uso dos recursos disponiveis pesará o computador, até o proprio C#.

Comment: Quando falo nisso não é nem questão das linguagens, pois isso depende mais do desenvolvedor. Mas quando citei isso foi mais em questão do usuário, que normalmente é leigo, e em empresas fica pior porque une pc fraco e usuário leigo, logo também se une vírus + lentidão do pc = culpa do sistema.

Comment: Começou tudo errado quando eu li a frase "Qual é a opinião de vocês". Talvez coubesse uma edição para a pergunta.

Comment: @diegofm você já desenvolveu alguma aplicação com javaFx para web? sabe me dizer se é bom?

Comment: @rray ao menos a minha pessoa jurídica não é kkk.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Todas as linguagens têm defeitos. Você lerá sobe os problemas de várias linguagens em vários lugares. Se for em um lugar onde o pessoal gosta de C#, ouvirá muito mal de Java. E o contrário é verdadeiro também. Não digo que as pessoas estão dizendo mentiras. Se for um local de bons profissionais, provavelmente serão verdades, talvez de forma um pouco tendenciosa. Leia tudo isso com cuidado. Procure outras fontes. E de modo geral não confie tanto em pessoas aleatórias na internet.

Códigos ruins causam bem mais problemas que linguagens ruins. Aprenda fazer códigos bons. Comece pelo fundamento. Entenda a computação como um todo. Não vá nas receitas de bolo, nas tais "boas práticas". Aprenda!

A maioria das linguagens atendem bem todo tipo de aplicação, não importa o que ela faz ou o porte dela. O seu problema parece ser claro para se resolver no desktop. Isso não há dúvidas. Java, C#, C++, Delphi, etc., todas trabalham bem com aplicações comerciais, incluindo equipamentos externos de automação, como PDV, TEF, etc.

As bibliotecas existentes são mais importantes que a linguagem. Vou citar algumas que possuem boas bibliotecas para a área de automação comercial.

Sabe mexer com alguma? Se sabe deveria ser um indicativo do que usar. As diferenças entre elas são pequenas para justificar a ideia de "usar a ferramenta certa para o problema". Nesse caso acho que cabe mais o **"a melhor ferramenta é aquela que você sabe"**.

## Analisando um pouco as linguagens

#### PHP e web

[PHP não costuma ser recomendado para desktop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133354/101). Acho até estranho saltar de Java para PHP. São filosofias muito diferentes. PHP é usada basicamente para *backend* web. Esqueça ela.

Esqueça a ideia de fazer esse tipo de aplicação como web, isso não dá certo. A experiência do usuário sofrerá e a integração com equipamentos externos é de sofrível a inviável.

#### Java

O Java não é tão ruim assim também. Se pode escolher, acho melhor escolher outra coisa, mas é só minha opinião, não escolha por causa disso. Só não descarte como opção válida. Ela não é tão lenta quanto dizem, já foi um dia (PHP é absurdamente mais lenta). E ela tem melhorado em cada versão.

Se já conhece bem ela, pode ser a melhor opção. Acho que ela não aproveita bem a GUI. Vejo até os Javeiros reclamarem que o JavaFX é para algum tipo bem específico de aplicação. Se for por esse caminho, pesquise mais sobre o assunto, faça perguntas aqui bem específicas sobre o assunto.

#### C#

Se Java não te atende, talvez a escolha recaia sobre [C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). Não sei se vai atender também. Não tem como afirmar o que é bom para você.

Para desktop, C# funciona muito bem no Windows. Há tecnologias que que se encaixam muito bem com o Windows disponíveis para C#.

Se precisar rodar em Linux dá também, mas não é tão bom (ainda que não seja exatamente pior que o que o Java oferece). O mesmo para MacOS. É um pouco melhor para o mundo mobile. Não é a preocupação inicial desse projeto, mas ele pode se expandir e precisar rodar nas 3 principais plataformas móveis.

A linguagem é totalmente gratuita, [tem todo seu código aberto](https://github.com/dotnet) e até o [Visual Studio quase completo é gratuito para a maioria das situações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101) (deve ser o seu caso).

Se não soubesse nada eu iria de C#. Mas reforço, é gosto pessoal.

#### C++

Alguns recomendariam [C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B), mas não é para iniciantes. Usando a [Qt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) é melhor se precisar que a aplicação rode em várias plataformas aproveitando tudo o que cada uma tem de melhor. Mas duvido que seja seu caso.

#### Algumas não tão adequadas

Outros diriam sobre o Delphi, eu particularmente considero tecnologia legada, ainda que não seja de fato. É uma linguagem paga, fechada e quase ninguém começa projetos novos nela. Só iria nela se você já estivesse muito confortável com ela. Aí será até uma opção técnica viável para Windows (não no Linux).

Não falarei de VB que é legado de fato e se for de VB.NET é melhor escolher C#, não vejo vantagens.

Outras linguagens de tipagem estática ou são legadas ou não estão maduras, ou não possuem boas bibliotecas para desktop (GUI), como Go, Rust, D, etc.

Não vou falar em linguagens de tipagem dinâmica específicas porque não parece ser a intenção original. Já vi alguma coisa em desktop usando Python. Não sei o nível de sucesso, mas vi bem pouca coisa. Uma aplicação grande que vi não era boa, mas não quer dizer que é culpa da linguagem. Mas também pode ser. Se a intenção original era Java, acho que esse tipo de linguagem será menos adequado, ainda que tecnicamente funcione.

#### Banco de dados

Use o que melhor te atende ou o que já domina. Se é o PostgreSQL, use-o. Não importa em que linguagem. Se tiver algum motivo pra escolher outro, escolha. São decisões independentes. Todas essas linguagens trabalham bem com ele, com o MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Firebird, SQLite ([é até uma opção para alguns](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100490/101)), entre outros. Todos funcionam em servidores.

Todos são ou possuem versões limitadas viáveis pra muita coisas gratuitas. Todos rodam nas principias plataformas (O SQL Server para Linux está quase pronto). Em mobile e cliente desktop só o SQLite é de fato viável no cliente. Há quem use o Firebird. Mas isso é outro assunto.

## Conclusão

Se está com uma dúvida tão básica sugeriria tentar achar alguém mais experiente para dividir o projeto e assim ir adquirindo a experiência necessária.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bom amigo, gostei da sua resposta ! e estou lendo aqui olha, eu faço faculdade de sistema de informação, e já aprendi várias linguagens, porém a dúvida é em que desenvolver eu vi que você indicou C# porém não é grátis certo? para eu comercializar os softwares desenvolvidos em C# eu teria que comprar a licença e isso está fora de contexto então para mim a ideia seria uma plataforma grátis, começei já a desenvolver em java, mais muitas pessoas me falaram "java é lento, não compensa" e eu acabei entrando em duvida,

Comment: A questão é em que desenvolver e você sabe me dizer se com java é facil a integração de PDV, TEF,?

Comment: É totalmente grátis e código totalmente aberto (https://github.com/dotnet), mais multi-plataforma que Java, inclusive o Visual Studio é grátis http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/101. O pessoal é muito desinformado e fica espalhando coisas erradas por aí. O resto está na resposta.

Comment: @bigown inclusive muita gente não sabe que o C# é ECMA ISO.

Comment: @Bruno Essa história de "java é lento, não compensa", era verdade em 1997, há quase 20 anos atrás. De lá para cá muuuuuita coisa mudou.

Comment: Então como não tenho nenhuma empresa e estou desenvolvendo sozinha se torna free, que bacana, dessa eu não sabia, pode me responder se o sqlserver, que vem junto com o c# tbm é gratis? e se você me recomendaria o desenvolvimento em WPF

Comment: @Bruno Novamente, são perguntas diferentes que precisam ser perguntadas em outro lugar. Mas sim, o SQL Server pode ser uado gratuitamente nas versões SQL Server Express o LocalDB (não sei se valerá para o Linux que só agora terá SQL Server), não vou entrar em detalhes. Mas pode continuar com o DB que achar melhor. Sobre Winforms, WPF, UWP, GTK, etc, é amplo demais pra falar aqui.

Answer (score 14):

Não vamos começar a velha competição entre linguagens de programação. Falar mal de `Java` porque a curva de aprendizado é grande ou falar bem de `PHP` porque não é tipada não é o caminho para sua resposta. Use a linguagem certa para o problema certo.

Você deve responder essa pergunta como lhe convier, mas um mapa para você começar é:

**1 - Primeiro erro é CONTROLE GERAL (isso não existe) Controle do quê?** Vai ter PDV (caixa), Integração com TEF ou é um controle simplesmente para depois ser jogado fora e evoluir um projeto maior? Porque se o mercado crescer sua solução vai ter tudo?

**2 - Web?** De jeito nenhum. Se for rodar em PDV você terá muitas dificuldades para integrar com impressoras fiscais tais como Bematech, TEFs, teclados específicos etc.

**3 - Software livre?** Vai rodar 100% em ambiente de software livre?

**4 - Quanto tempo de projeto e quais requisitos funcionais?** Os requisitos não funcionais podem deixar sua decisão de PHP no chão facilmente.

Enfim, alguém deu -1 na sua questão. São perguntas que todo iniciante tem, e se alguém me desse essa resposta que estou te dando, não teria quebrado a cara em dois projetos que queria fazer "rapidinho" um "controle geral", no início da minha carreira.

Comment: Bom gostei da sua resposta ! e realmente eu não havia pensado nessa parte de integração com impressoras fiscais e os teclados específicos ... A ideia não é ser um projeto tão simples, ele iria contar com funções basicas como cadastros de fornecedor, clientes, funcionarios, produtos, categorias ... e teria algumas funções funcionais como realizar venda, compra, lançar contas a pagar, quitar contas a pagar e receber ... porém agora estou em uma enorme dúvida, o projeto já foi começado em java e seria necessario algo totalmente free tbm por isso não optei por c#

Comment: Com relação a java você sabe me dizer se é fácil integrar as impressoras fiscais e os teclados específicos ?

Comment: @Bruno que legal. Muita gente que desenvolve para a web por exemplo, cria portais, sites, etc não tem ideia da "DOR DE CABEÇA" que é desenvolver por exemplo uma solução de Nota Fiscal Eletrônica. por questões burocráticas, legislação etc. Por isso minha resposta foi foco no seu problema e não na ferramenta. Pense nos "módulos" e te ajudamos com a arquitetura :-) talvez envolva muito mais linguagem do que você possa imaginar. Uma vez prestei consultoria para um supermercado colocando PROLOG para otimizar a localização dos produtos nas prateleiras, para você ter ideia de onde chega a coisa.

Comment: @Bruno com relação a integração com impressoras fiscais, TEFs etc, é bem fácil (quando digo fácil é a questão de "comunicação" não de legislação). Muitas empresas disponibilizam APIs prontas para isto. A Bematech por exemplo tem isso pronto para diversas linguagens: VB, C#, Java, C++ etc. Elabore tudo o que tem que ter no mínimo em cada módulo e podemos te ajudar a montar uma "arquitetura" para começar.

Comment: Bom Mateus a arquitetura em questão contaria com 2 computadores interligados, onde 1 deles atuaria tbm como servidor! o programa rodaria em ambas maquinas, e seria possivel efetuar a venda e compra dos produtos contendo todas funcionalidades basicas e tbm sendo possivel gerar nota fiscal eletrônica e etc! Agora a duvida principal é a LP para resolver esse problema, qual devo usar? a principio me dou bem com C# e não sabia que era possivel usar de graça, até que o @bigown citou em um comentario logo abaixo e tbm me dou bem com java, a intenção então era fazer uma aplicação desktop levando em

Comment: consideração o uso de uma linguagem free um sgbd tbm! até passou pela minha cabeça fazer algo web mais como você disse se torna algo mais complexo para fazer a emissão das notas e etc. bom agora o problema realmente é, qual lp devo usar e qual sgbd?

Comment: Agora vou responder com a minha opinião: uma arquitetura que vai ser grande de início (parece uma orquestra) porém posteriormente se o mercado crescer, tiver outras filiais pode ser melhor e você entenderá de acordo com sua experiência com Java. Java com Swing nos terminais de venda PDVs (não usaria JavaFx) integrando com EJB (nos EJB, implementações JPA e SGBD MySQL). EJBs para tudo. Nada de regra de negócio em módulos em Jars e em partes separadas. Regras de negócio nos meus EJBs sempre, para a manutenção ficar mais concentrada nos componentes de negócio. Toda integração com NFe com EJBs.

Comment: Com isso você quer dizer que minha regra de negocio fica toda no banco, correto ?

Comment: Porque você acha que deveria utilizar Swing ao inves de JavaFX?

Comment: @Bruno abra novas perguntas com dúvidas específicas, há até um discussão no chat sobe esta pergunta se ela deve ser fechada por ser opinativa, não clara ou ampla. Os seus comentários está torando ela ampla demais. Aqui não é um fórum, não á para ficar debatendo o assunto, dúvidas novas serão bem-vindas em perguntas novas.

Answer (score 10):

Bem, isso é uma pergunta opinativa, mas vamos lá.

Primeiro:

> porém comecei a ler sobre Java e achei muitos contras sobre essa linguagem de programação

Quais contras você achou? Há vários contras de fato, mas todas as linguagens tem seus prós e contras. E também há muita gente que tende a exarcebar os contras para um nível maior do que eles são na prática.

Por exemplo, há muita gente por aí que repete o mantra de que "java é lento". Isso era bem verdade em 1997. Passados quase 20 anos, muuuuuuita coisa mudou. Por causa disso, sempre que você ver uma crítica a uma linguagem, analise o contexto em que ela é válida, pois muitas vezes são casos específicos ou casos que não se aplicam mais. Analise quando a crítica foi feita, embasada em quais fatos e se isso se aplica ao seu caso. Além disso, há muita gente falando besteiras ou então as espalhando como papagaios. Tome cuidado com isso.

Em especial, no caso do JavaFX, ele é bem rápido para o que ele se propõe a fazer, sendo um bom competidor em relação ao Flash e uma alternativa desktop muito boa caso você não queira ir para uma solução baseada em HTML5.

Por exemplo, eu poderia fazer uma crítica e publicar em algum lugar na internet de que "*Delphi não é bom para fazer animações de jogos, pois tentei fazer isso e falhei miseravelmente, devido ao intenso flickering*". Entretanto, esta crítica não seria válida a menos que eu provasse que a forma como eu estava tentando desenvolver era de fato a melhor (e eu duvido que tenha sido), de que eu já teria exaurido as possibilidades das demais alternativas viáveis (muito improvável) e que nenhuma outra solução haveria surgido em tempo futuro (improvável também a menos que a minha publicação fosse muito recente e muito aprofundada). Além disso, o fato de não ter sido satisfatório para mim, não significa que não seria para você, uma vez que o seu problema é diferente do meu (o seu sistema provavelmente não precisará usar esse tipo de coisa).

Outra frequente reclamação é que Java é muito verboso. Isso é verdade, apesar que mudanças na linguagem como por exemplo os lambdas do Java 8 e algumas ideias que devem ser implementadas no Java 9 estão a reduzir a verbosidade. Novamente, vale olhar para o contexto histórico da crítica. E embora isso possa ser chato, de forma alguma seria um impeditivo sério.

Por fim, eu digo que já vi muitos sistemas feitos com Java Desktop por aí rodando muito bem. Para citar um caso concreto, talvez você conheça a rede de farmácias DrogaRaia/Drogasil. Pois bem, o sistema deles é em Java tanto no cliente quanto no servidor, e a parte cliente usa o Swing (que é o precursor/embasamento do JavaFX). Não digo que a implementação do sistema deles é boa ou que é ruim, pois não conheço, mas isso demonstra bem o fato de que esse tipo de coisa existe sim no mundo real. E esse sistema integra com impressora fiscal e tudo mais.

Além disso, o fato de você estar pensando em usar para web em PHP mostra um outro problema mais profundo:

> Como você quer que o sistema seja usado? Quem o usará? Onde ele será usado? É para responder a essas perguntas que você vai decidir se fará em desktop ou web (ou alguma outra alternativa, ex: mobile). Não é a opção pela linguagem de programação que determinará isso, e sim o contrário.

Quanto a emissão de notas fiscais, se está a falar de notas fiscais eletrônicas (NF-e), eu posso afirmar que já trabalhei em dois sistemas diferentes para a emissão de NF-e's em Java. Um deles era desktop usando Swing e o outro era web usando Tomcat. Além disso, sei que as secretarias de fazenda de alguns estados usam Java web na parte do servidor enquanto outras usam C#. Em geral, o sistema de NF-e do governo foi (mal-)projetado pensando-se na integração com Java e C# especificamente via webservices (por meio de WSDL e SOAP). Não que não seja possível com outras linguagens, e certamente deve ter gente que conseguiu fazer isso com PHP, Python, Delphi ou qualquer outra coisa, mas o foco principal foi especificamente Java e C#.

Quanto a impressão de cupons fiscais de supermercado, pode ter certeza que há disponibilidade para isso em quase qualquer linguagem de programação desktop sendo usada de forma séria atualmente. Para sistemas web isso é mais díficil porque a impressora fiscal é um hardware específico que não estará disponível para uso no navegador (a menos que você tenha algum plugin maluco para o Chrome ou coisa assim, o que acho bem improvável de que exista) e você quer que a impressão seja feita no cliente que está no caixa e não no servidor. Formas de fazer o servidor se comunicar com a impressora do cliente só tornarão as coisas desnecessariamente mais difíceis.

Quanto a possibilidade de os computadores não aguentarem o JavaFX, isso provavelmente é besteira. Exceto no caso de eles sejam realmente muuuuuuito antigos (ex: 486 usando DOS e Windows 95) e não possam ser atualizados de forma alguma impossibilitando a instalação de qualquer JVM decente neles. Só vislumbro como hipóteses realistas para esse caso, uma empresa com computadores bem velhos nos caixas que esteja a beira da falência para não ter dinheiro para atualizá-los ou que simplesmente se recuse a fazê-lo por ser gerenciada com grandes doses de pura e simples negligência e burrice (ou mais provavelmente todos esses fatores juntos), e em qualquer um desses casos, você terá outros problemas bem piores para enfrentar. Entretanto, mesmo se for este o caso, qualquer coisa que você for tentar rodar neles vai ser bem ruim a menos que você trabalhe com uma tecologia bem velha ou desenvolva um sistema web para Internet Explorer 6 ou coisa pior.

Enfim, se você precisa usar a impressora fiscal do caixa do supermercado, acho que isso elimina a possibilidade de usar um sistema web. Caso contrário, essa possibilidade continua em aberto. Não digo que você deva ou não fazer em Java, mas até agora você não mostrou nada que possa eliminar essa alternativa.

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta, e compreendi o que você quis dizer! Pode ser bom para realizar algumas coisas e para outras não e realmente vai depender de quem usa!  no exemplo citado com relação as farmacias eu conheço, porém não o sistema!
Meu sistema no caso seria usado em um mini mercado, usado apenas pelos "vendedores" e "administradores" em questão ... porém como havia dito não sei se os computadores deles são bons, para rodar uma aplicação por isso cogitei a hipótese de ser web pois sei que ao menos um navegador iria suportar, porém se fosse web eu teria muitos problemas com relação

Comment: a emissão de notas fiscais e coisas do gênero

Comment: @Bruno Estava escrevendo um comentário para responder esses seus novos questionamentos, mas ficou longo demais e por isso editei a resposta. :D

Answer (score 3):

Já existem várias opiniões e respostas boas sobre sua situação. Mas uma sugestão que posso lhe dar é que se você já está e pretende continuar a desenvolver em JAVA, recomendo usar o Java EE para desenvolver seu projeto WEB. Meu TCC por exemplo foi elaborado em cima de uma aplicação desktop Java e fizemos uma versão WEB com JSP, JSTL e etc... a forma de se trabalhar não é tão diferente e você pode manter muitas regras de negócio adaptando pouco código por exemplo.

Caso queira ver um exemplo de código JAVA EE, meu TCC está no Github.
https://github.com/pedr0369/ProjetoPizzariaEureka