# É possível criar aplicações de console em PHP no estilo Clipper?

Tags: php, console

Parece coisa de outro planeta, mas eu gostaria de ver uma linguagem atual fazendo coisas antigas, tipo um PHP fazendo uma aplicação estilo Clipper, aquela de telas com linhas simples, mas muito eficientes pra época.

Não vou entrar no mérito dificuldade ou viabilidade, eu já faço aplicações *desktop* com PHP em *intranets* e vou dizer uma coisa, juntando jQuery e CSS com PHP dá pra fazer muita coisa.

Sei que posso executar o PHP em linha de comando e já faço isso no Cron do Linux, mas gostaria de ir além, criar aplicações com interfaces como Clipper, Cobol e outras da era antiga, rsrs

É possível, existem bibliotecas para isso?

Comment: A eficiência do Clipper é a robustez da linguagem, e não a "Tela simples" (tanto que o sucessor moderno do Clipper é o Harbour, que vai muito bem hoje, e deixa qualquer PHP no chinelo). O fato é que se você tratar o console pelo PHP da mesma forma que o General Terminal do Clipper, vai conseguir coisas "parecidas", mas a falta de especialização do PHP em aplicações comerciais vai sempre atrapalhar. Em especial, a leitura de teclas, e coordenadas de exibição, falta de tipo nativo de data, etc. Em resumo: fazer aplicação console em PHP para interação com usuário comumente é andar pra trás.

Comment: Hum, muito produtivo para mim essa discussão, não fazia ideia do quão pode ser complexo usar php para uma aplicação console.

Comment: Não é pela complexidade, é mais pelo fato de não ter sido feito pra isso. No Harbour você vai gerar um executável que faz tudo, e a linguagem foi pensada em aplicação comercial. PHP foi feito para scripts, não tem "alma" de coisa que fica rodando em loop, apesar de possível. Já vi umas duas ou três aplicações feitas em PHP pra "uso contínuo", muito bem escritas (sem essas bobagens de querer usar OOP à toa em linguagem de script), mas são raridades. Até pouco tempo atrás o SMTP do Guerrillamail era PHP puro. E o código é um exemplo de programação de verdade. O fato é que estes casos são exceção

Comment: Em tempo: a crítica ao PHP é apenas no contexto mencionado. Eu uso regularmente PHP para coisas de PHP: scripts para aplicações web de baixa e média demanda, para entrega rápida e facilidade de manutenção, sem problemas. É como ter aquele amigo que é metido a sabichão, bebe, é esquecido e fala umas besteiras de vez em quando, mas como você conhece ele bem, sabe onde e quando pode contar com ele e quando não pode, então não dá margem pra problemas, e convive bem com ele.

Comment: Procure bibliotecas que permitam usar NCurses a partir do PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possível é. Adequado não. Seria bom usar uma biblioteca que dê acesso a um console um pouco mais sofisticado como [Ncurses](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php) e [Termbox](https://github.com/adsr/termbox-php).

Na verdade [aplicação com GUI em PHP eu já fiz e é trágico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/133375/101), console não é muito diferente, a linguagem não foi criada para isto.

Eu tenho medo de recomendar qualquer coisa para quem gosta de Clipper porque o histórico não é bom, mas [se quer usar o Clipper continue com ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43902/101). Ainda é bem atual, na minha opinião, mais que o PHP. Uma linguagem que foi feita para praticamente qualquer coisa, exceto fazer sistemas operacionais e coisas do tipo.

No Harbour pode usar o esquema de console tradicional do Clipper ou usar outros suportes de console, usar GUI decente, bancos de dados variados, incluindo SQLite e MySQL que as pessoas usam em PHP, ou ficar no DBF. Pode fazer algo para web, usar XML, JSON, criptografia, e todas essas coisas modernas, além de rodar em muitos sistemas operacionais, 32 ou 64 bits.

Comment: Não, eu não manjo de Clipper, só citei como exemplo por ser  conhecido, eu queria fazer alguma coisa mas sem ter que aprender uma nova linguagem, eu programo em Delphi, já pensei no Pascal para isso, mas parei, nem fui pra frente, já li pouca coisa de Harbour, não sei se é fácil de aprender e não faço ideia do poder dela, mas interessante sua dica, vou pensar no caso.