# Orientação a objetos do PHP dá pra criar qualquer tipo de site e projeto?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Eu sem querer acabei pegando um projeto freelancer, e queria ter noção sobre se devo ou não focar em OO por que é mais organizado pra esse meu projeto e até pra aprender .Tenho noção sobre a estruturada, mas é bem confuso.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 6):

> Orientação a objetos do PHP dá pra criar qualquer tipo de site e projeto?

Sim, dá. Assim como [qualquer linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101) pode resolver qualquer problema.

O pessoal fazia sites quando PHP não tinha facilidades de orientação a objeto e ia muito bem. Tem quem faça assim até hoje e não troca por nada.

PHP tem muitas facilidades para criar sites. Praticamente todas linguagens hoje tem, algumas até melhor.

Não tente fazer [projetos que não sejam web em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107280/101), ela é muito fraca para isso, tem várias desvantagens e problemas.

> Eu sou novo tanto aqui quanto em programação, muito novo mesmo. (originalmente estava na pergunta)

Então seria melhor dominar a parte fácil que é a imperativa, entender todo o básico antes de se aventurar em uma paradigma que exige muita experiência para fazer certo.

> eu sem querer acabei pegando um projeto freelancer

Se não quer, não pegue. Se acha que não tem condições de fazer, não faça. Principalmente para web é um perigo fazer algo sem muito domínio de muita coisa na computação. Por isso tem tanta coisa errada e insegura por aí.

> queria ter noção sobre se devo ou não focar em OO por que é mais organizado pra esse meu projeto e até pra aprender.

Só você pode dizer o que deve fazer.

OOP só é mais organizado para quem sabe organizar. E não é fácil organizar. Na verdade o que vemos frequentemente, quase o tempo todo, é o pessoal tentando fazer OO, não conseguindo e bagunçando mais ainda. E pior, as pessoas [acha que está fazendo certo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) e não precisa melhorar.

> Tenho noção sobre a estruturada, mas é bem confuso.

Se acha algo muito simples como confuso, espere para entrar em algo muito mais confuso.

Na verdade noto que muitas pessoas não entendem nem o significado da expressão programação estruturada. Aí qualquer coisa fica confuso. Tanto que 99+% falam que fazem OOP e pelo menos 90% do seu código é imperativo onde OOP nada tem a ver. Muitos acham que estão fazendo OOP nos outros 10% porque ele cria classes ou faz algo parecido. Mas ele faz tudo errado. Funciona, mas não obtém o que OOP mais prega que é a manutibilidade.

## Adendo

Com advento de OOP em PHP a linguagem ficou esquisita, tem partes que ela prega uma coisa, em outras prega outra. Então boa parte do que OOP poderia ajudar na verdade é uma ilusão e não ajuda.

Existe uma corrente que diz que OOP é o que Smalltalk faz, existe outra que diz que é o que C++ faz. PHP, pelo seu histórico, e conjunto de *features*  tinha tudo para adotar o estilo de Smalltalk, mas optou pelo estilo de C++ que exige coisas que PHP não tem.

Nem tudo precisa de OOP, a maioria dos sites não precisam. Por isso que não entendo essa obsessão com o paradigma. OS projetos que precisam mesmo são conduzidos por pessoas experientes e pragmáticas ou fica ruim de alguma forma.